# What information is added to the files when we add a dll references in Visual Studio project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dll, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I am creating a sample WP8 application. When we add a new dll in reference folder, which files get updated or which file store information about this dll. Basically i want to know what changes occur in complete project when we add a new dll in reference folder.

Comment: Open .csproj file in text editor and see what information is added.

Comment: Nothing is getting changed in .csprpoj file. I am making a wp8 app.

Comment: Use source control and a diff tool to see exact changes.

Comment: I tried using diff tool. There are no changes in csproj file.

Answer (score 0):

If you reference a file dll somewhere on your machine, that reference will be written to the .csproj file.  As stated in the comments you can use a text editor on the csproj file to see it.

If you add a reference via NuGet, the csproj will be updated as above but the packages.config file will also be updated, with a line about that particular package and version of that package.

Comment: Hi Scott. I tried the same as mentioned in the comments above but there is no changes that are happening in csproj file after adding some dlls